# Efficient implementation of matrix multiplication ARM cortex A9 - Xilinx SDK

Tags: c, arm, linear-algebra, xilinx, zynq

Is there any simple way-library to efficient (max possible speed) implement linear algebra on an ARM CortexA9 dual core using *Xilinx SDK*?

I am using a zybo z7 developememt board with a dual core Arm proccesor and i want to implement a simple neural network with one convolution layer followed by a dense one, on Xilinx SDK. Specificaly, to tranfer a python numpy based model on Arm. I read some manuals for ARM and SIMD library but i don't want to dive so deep.

An easy way for me is to use a library and do the multiplication/dot product/convolve etc by itself (fast) like numpy in python and avoid pure for...loop syntax. An example would be nice!

Thank for your time

Comment: If you are asking for a recommendation on a library, you should ask elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library used by Tensorflow to implement the matrix calculations, or you can even try to use [TensorFlow lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/microcontrollers) which is already tested with the ARM-Cortex M series of processors.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works with high performane